# How to use for="{{item}}"?

Tags: angular

Every `{{item}}` works well except `for="{{item}}"`. It shows:

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a
>   known native property

```
<div *ngFor="#item of collection">
    <input type="radio" name="item" id="{{item}}" value="{{item}}">
    <label for="{{item}}">
        {{item}}
    </label>
</div>
```

How can I make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'for' since it isn't a known native property angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229960/cant-bind-to-for-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-property-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` isn't an property, it's only an attribute. Use instead explicit attribute binding:

```
 <label [attr.for]="item">
```

or

```
 <label attr.for="{{item}}">
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement "`htmlFor` (DOMString) The ID of the labeled control. Reflects the `for` attribute."

Comment: For people who also don't know difference between property and attribute, this is useful: http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/attribute-vs-property/

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement "`htmlFor` (DOMString) The ID of the labeled control. Reflects the `for` attribute."